# Rename multiple files in multiple subdirectories using for loop

Tags: shell-script, rename, for

I am trying to rename files with the same names in different subdirectories using for loop.They should be renamed according to the name of subdirectory.

```
Subdirectory1/File.txt
Subdirectory2/File.txt
```

should look like

```
Subdirectory1/Subdirectory1.txt
Subdirectory2/Subdirectory2.txt
```

I tried many commands and I am getting different errors. The last command, which I found on forum also doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

```
dir="Subdirectory1, Subdirectory2"
declare -i count=1 for file in "$dir"/*.txt; do
mv "$file" "${dir}/${dir} ${count}.txt"
count+=1
done
```

After running this, I get:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘/*/*.txt’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Loop across the list of directories
for dir in Subdirectory1 Subdirectory2
do
    # Only consider directories
    [ -d "$dir" ] || continue

    # Loop across any files in each directory
    for src in "$dir"/*.txt
    do
        dst="$dir/$dir.txt"
        
        # Only rename a file if it won't overwrite another one
        if [ -f "$dst" ]
        then
            # Refuse to overwrite
            echo "Target file already exists: $dst" >&2
        else
            # If the file already has the right name just skip
            [ -f "$src" ] && [ "$src" != "$dst" ] && mv -f -- "$src" "$dst"
        fi
    done
done
```

Prepare the script (let's say it's called `renamethem`) with `chmod a+x renamethem`. And then run it as `./renamethem`.

You'll see the list of directories is hard-coded in the `for` loop. There are a couple of other ways to handle this a little more elegantly. You could provide the list on the command line (`./renamethem Subdirectory1 Subdirectory2`) in which case change one line to `for dir in "$@"` to pick the parameters from that command line. Or you could use an array (list). Or you could use `*` to match all directories in the current directory.

Comment: Thank you very much! It finally works :D

Comment: If this answer solved your issue please would you accept it with the ✔ tickmark in the corner. This shows everyone else that this solution worked best for you and that your question has been answered successfully